# Data loss when moving the data between S3 buckets

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, amazon-cognito

Do we loose the data when the data movement happens between s3 buckets.

```
S3 landing bucket(zip files data) -> S3 staging bucket(zip files data)
```

In above flow, do we loose the data while moving the data to s3 staging bucket from landing bucket?

Note: Data is in zip file. Here I'm talking about only the data loss.

Comment: How are you copying the data between the buckets?

Comment: We are using lambda

Comment: Is your Lambda function issuing a `CopyObject` command to Amazon S3? If so, data is either copied or not copied. If it is copied, then the destination file is complete. A file is only removed from the source bucket if you issue a `DeleteObject` command. Data in Amazon S3 is replicated to three different data centers. It's probably more reliable than your own storage.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the data movement applications handle the reliable transfer. It works like below.

> Copy --> Verify --> Delete

It copies from source to destination, verifies whether the destination is intact as the source. Then deletes the source file.

Please confirm whether the implementation of the software handles reliable transfers.

If you use aws s3 cli, then YES.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do we loose the data in the target s3 bucket? In what scenarios the Data in the file might loose??

Comment: We have had close to half a billions s3 objects and never has even a single failure so far. Even when s3 services failed, you will receive proper error in your applications, never seen a data loss yet.